# pass list of interface that is used in a Class to constructor

Tags: kotlin

I have two interfaces that have 2 different variables.
I created a class that implements these 2 interfaces.
Now I want to pass a list of the first interface to a constructor of another class and use its property (from both interfaces). So far I succeeded to have the constructor but I couldn't find how to pass the list of params

```
interface A {
    var name: String
}

interface B {
    var job: String
}

class C(
    override var name: String,
    override var job: String
) : A, B

class D() {
    private fun getList() {
        val list: List<A> = arrayListOf(
            C("user1", "job1"),
            C("user2", "job2"),
            C("user3", "job3")
        )
        // I want to init E() my constructor here 
    }
}

class E<T>(val list: List<T>) where T : A, T: B {
    fun display() {
        list.forEach {
            println("my name is ${list.get(i).name} and I am a ${list.get(i).job}")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding a bit on the answer that @Scrobot gave.

In short terms you cannot do what you are trying to do. When you specify `List<A>` as the type, you leave out information about if the elements in your list implements interface B.

If you could do what you try to do, you could very easily break your code by doing things like:

```
class PureA : A {
    override var name: String
}

val list: List<A> = arrayListOf(
    C("user1", "job"),
    PureA("user2")
)

// The following line will not work, and for good reason
// E(list)
```

If the last line worked you would basically break your code. PureA is a valid element in a List of As, but it is not of E.

The following is a lot closer to what you intend to do:

```
// Doesn't work fully
class D<T> where T: A, T: B {
    private fun getList(): E<T> {
        val list: List<T> = arrayListOf<T>(
            C("user1", "job1"),
            C("user2", "job2"),
            C("user3", "job3")
        )

        E(list)
    }
}
```

I could not see a complete way to finalize what you what to do. I assume that you want to allow future classes that implement A and B too. Only way I've found that would work is:

```
interface AB : A, B

class C(
        override var name: String,
        override var job: String
) : AB

class D {
    private fun getList() {
        val list: List<AB> = arrayListOf(
            C("user1", "job1"),
            C("user2", "job2"),
            C("user3", "job3")
        )

        E(list)
        // I want to init E() my constructor here
    }
}
```

Which is a perfectly good solution, even though it gives you more interefaces. But that is usually perfectly fine :)

Comment: can you just explain to me what will be my E class constructor will look like in my case?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your question, Your code needs just a little improvement to solve your problem

```
interface A {
    var name: String
}

interface B {
    var job: String
}

class C(
    override var name: String,
    override var job: String
) : A, B

class D {
    fun getList(): E<C> = E(
        arrayListOf(
            C("user1", "job1"),
            C("user2", "job2"),
            C("user3", "job3")
        )
    )
}

class E<T>(val list: List<T>) where T : A, T: B {
    fun display() {
        // for (i in 1..10) will throw OutOfBoundsException
        list.forEach {
            println("my name is ${it.name} and I am a ${it.job}")
        }
    }
}

// to test
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    D().getList().display()

    /* will prints
       my name is user1 and I am a job1
       my name is user2 and I am a job2
       my name is user3 and I am a job3 */
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , sorry about the loop it's correct what you fixed but that's not my problem. I want to call E class inside D class but I don't know how to pass the list as a param !

Comment: You couldn't pass `List<T>` as param because your `T` should implement interfaces `A` and `B`. It's just your class `C`. But you initialize a list of interface `A` in `val list: List<A> = arrayListOf()`. Change it to `List<C>` and then you can call E constructor with list parameter `E(list)`

Comment: what if I have many classes that implements A and B just like C

Comment: how can I put them in the List

Comment: It means that you should to change class `C` to the abstract class. And then you can extend some other classes with `C` and make `List<C>`